# Query to turn rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In some business applications, raw data comes in, I normalize and process them, and store them for reporting purpose.

For example, raw data:

`Transaction (transaction ID, employee 1 ID, employee 2 ID, employee 3 ID)`

is normalized into

`Transaction(transaction ID)`

`TransactionEmployee (transaction ID, employee ID)`

When it comes to reporting requirements, employees have to appear in one row - like `TransactionReport(transaction ID, some details, employee 1 ID, employee 2 ID, employee 3 ID)`

My solution has been to use an application programming language to loop TransactionEmployee, and construct INSERT statement to put reporting data into another table - each transaction with 3 employee IDs.

But I would feel more comfortable to do it in SQL.

Is this feasible via SQL?

Comment: Your google search string is "mysql pivot query".  By the way, can a transaction have more than 3 employees?

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you. Transaction will not have more than 3 associated employees. I have heard of pivot query but feel naughty to do `select limit 1` then `select limit 1 skip 1` then `select limit 1 skip 2`. Wonder if there is a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you could do this would be to use user defined variables to create a row number for each employee per transaction, then you could convert the rows of data into column by applying an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select transactionid,
  max(case when row = 1 then employeeid end) employee1,
  max(case when row = 2 then employeeid end) employee2,
  max(case when row = 3 then employeeid end) employee3
from
(
  select t.transactionid,
    e.employeeid,
    @row:=case when @prev = t.transactionid then @row else 0 end +1 row,
    @prev:=t.transactionid
  from transaction t
  left join transactionemployee e
    on t.transactionid = e.transactionid
  cross join (select @row:=0, @prev = 0) c
  order by t.transactionid, e.employeeid
) d
group by transactionid
order by transactionid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44c4e/2).

If you don't want to use the user defined variables then you could use a subquery similar to the following:

```
select transactionid,
  max(case when row = 1 then employeeid end) employee1,
  max(case when row = 2 then employeeid end) employee2,
  max(case when row = 3 then employeeid end) employee3
from
(
  select t.transactionid,
    e.employeeid,
    (select count(*)
     from transactionemployee te
     where e.transactionid = te.transactionid
       and te.employeeid <= e.employeeid) row
  from transaction t
  left join transactionemployee e
    on t.transactionid = e.transactionid
) d
group by transactionid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44c4e/5)